# Poles of $f$ when considering $\dot{x} = f(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am looking at an ODE of the form
\begin{align}
\dot{x} = f(x).
\end{align}
Do poles of $f$ give me boundaries for the maximal solution $\lambda(t)$ of an ODE of this form?

For example:

\begin{align}
\dot{x} = \frac{1}{\sin(x)},\qquad  x(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align} Obviously $x = 0$ and $x = \pi$ are poles of $\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$. Can I conclude that the maximal solution $\lambda$ of this initial value problem fulfills $0 < \lambda(t) < \pi$ for all $t$ of the maximal interval of existence? In this particular case: Does it allow me to conclude that the maximal solution exists for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the solution must be continuous, and it cannot take a value which makes $\dot x$ undefined, so it can't go outside the interval $(0,\pi)$.

But no, you can't conclude that the maximal interval of existence is $\mathbb{R}$, since if you simply solve the ODE using separation of variables, you get
$$
x(t) = \arccos(-t)
,\quad
-1 < t < 1
.
$$